# How to store passwords on hard drive the right way?

Tags: security, passwords, gmail, password-protection, autoit

A script is used to send emails (only with Gmail) daily with user interactions. I would like to store their e-mail in hard drive in a plain text file. What is the right way to do it ?

- I know one method would be to ask a user for a password to protect the e-mail password, but this method is pointless because the user should type in a new password every time an email is sent, so I rather ask their e-mail password instead.
- Another way would be to encrypt the password and using a key with combination of specific informations to user like computer name+username+system+... and use this same key to decrpyt the encrypted password. The problem with this, that I'm using [Autoit](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/) which is easy to decompile, so when a potencial attacker got the encrypted password, they could theoretically know the encryption key so doesn't matter who many uniq information I use for encrypt the password, they could get it anyway.
- Another way would be to use OAuth for gmail, so the user doesn't need to type in password at all but I can't do that.

Any ideas ?

Comment: What OS? Programming environment? (I ask as some OSs & frameworks have facilities to help you)

Comment: Language is [Autoit](http://autoitscript.com) script and it is for Windows only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Eric has mentioned, DPAPI is the way to go if you are using Windows. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx
The function CryptProtectData() uses the Windows logon information for that particular user to encrypt the data so that no other user on the system can decyrpt the plain text which you store.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're programming on Windows, I would suggest looking in to Windows APIs to do the crypto work for you. You can trust they are better than what you'd probably invent yourself, assuming you are not willing ot make different assumptions (ex: TPM).

On Win8 there is now a PasswordVault class, if you want to target that OS.
On <=Win7, there is DPAPI and Credential Manager

None of this is GMail specific...this is just generic "storing stuff securely on Windows" sorts of advice. There very well might be a better gmail-specific way (ex: service specific credential) that you should pursue. But even if you did that, this is a better way to approach storing it on the client OS.

Answer (score -1):

AutoIt has _Crypt...() functions to use for this. You can hash the @computername or @username and use the hash as a key for the _Crypt_DeriveKey() function to localize its usage of the password. Then use the key to pass into _Crypt_EncryptData() targeting the password string as the data. Store the encrypted key in your plain text file.

When you go to call it back, read the file, create the key again with _Crypt_DeriveKey() and then decrypt it with _Crypt_DecryptData(). The output of the latter function should be your password.

Crypt.au3 utilizes the WinAPI functions for encryption.

Comment: you did not read the question, I hate that...
Second bullet point. I did exactly the same but I didn't liked it.
I want a solution in which you can see the encryption method (the code) and still not able to decrypt the password.

Comment: I've heard that the newest version of AutoIt is harder to decompile, as the decompiler used for the older versions doesn't work with the newest one. This is info I've seen from different sources. Unfortunately, the topic of decompiling is off limits in the autoitscript.com forums, so I can't confirm this. Also, the accepted answer is pretty much the same as mine. Both ways access the WinAPI to perform the encryption... so I thought I'd give the answer for utilizing the UDF with AutoIt. So either way, if someone decompiles it, they'll see either _Crypt...() or DllCall() targeting the API DLL

Comment: To fix the above comment, they won't see the actual functions, but the C++ code for calling the WinAPI for the encrypt functions. So they will be synonymous.